# When working with objects that are saved to a database that have a relationship, do you load the whole objects or just the id?

Tags: java, mysql, oop

Suppose I have a CatHerder and he has Cats, when I getCatHerderByID(String id) should I load in the CatHerder and set an arrayList of cats or an arrayList of catIDs?

Comment: Doesn't the answer depend upon what you're trying to do? Id might be enough, or you might want Id plus some basic information about the CatHerder.

Comment: When I want the details of a particular cat, I want the most up-to-date information, so wouldn't I want to only store the id and then if I was viewing the information on a particular cat I would probably want to get each cat by id.

Comment: Gotcha. I agree with syrion's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCatHerderByID()` should be a method which returns an object of type `CatHerder`, which can have a property `catsOwned` which will contain a list of IDs, populated by the constructor.  In addition, you can have a method on the `CatHerder` object called `getCats()` which returns an array of `Cat` consisting of the IDs in the `CatHerder` object. You shouldn't load unnecessary information just because it has a relationship with the information you actually want -- in many cases, *everything* will have a relationship with the data you actually want.

Comment: This is 100% exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have much data or many concurrent users, you can go with either way.

One easy options would be to add an additional parameter specifying whether to return a "deep copy" including the relations, or just the attributes of the object itself.

Stay away from the urge to add more parameters, or you will end up re-implementing SQL :)